# $p(z) = 1 + 2z + 3z^2 + \dots + (n+1)z^n$ has no zeroes in a disk for sufficiently large $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $0 < r < 1$.  I need to prove that $p(z) = 1 + 2z + 3z^2 + \dots +(n+1)z^n$ has no zeroes in the disk $|z| < r$ if $n$ is sufficiently large.  I'm thinking Rouche's theorem might be helpful, but I'm not exactly sure how to apply it. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the coefficients here. Is the general coefficient $k z^k$ or $(k+1)z^k$, or is the last different than the rest?

Comment: Sorry, correction made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)z^k$, and $p(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$. Note that $p$ is analytic on $B(0,1)$ and has no zeros or poles in $B(0,1)$.

Find a lower bound for $|p(z)|$ on $B(0,1)$.

Hint:

> If $|z|<1$, we have  $|1-z| < 2$, hence $|p(z)|> \frac{1}{4}$.

Choose $r \in (0,1)$, and $r < s <1$. Then show that $p_n \to p$ uniformly on $B(0,s)$. Find a suitable upper bound for $|p_n(z) -p(z)|$ in $B(0,s)$.

Hint:

> Now choose $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, we have $|p_n(z) -p(z)| \le \frac{1}{4}$ for all $z \in B(0,s)$.

Finally, apply Rouché's theorem on $|z|=r$.

> Hence if $|z|=r$, we have $|p_n(z) -p(z)| \le \frac{1}{4} < |p(z)|$. We conclude from Rouché's theorem that $p_n$ the same number of zeros as $p$ in $B(0,r)$ (that is, zero zeros).

Comment: Can you explain why $p_n \to p$ uniformly?  Is it because $p_n \to p$ uniformly on the compact disk $|z| \le s$?

Comment: Rouché is a bit overkill here: if $p_n(z) = 0$ we immediately get the contradiction $|p(z)| < |p(z)|$.

Comment: @user66825: The power series of $p$ converges inside the radius of convergence ($R=1$), and uniformly on compact subsets of $B(0,R)$. And as you noted, $\overline{B}(0,s)$ is compact.

Comment: @ErickWong: This is true, but the OP mentioned Rouché. Also, to some extent, this is the nature of Rouché's theorem...

Comment: @copper.hat You're right, I hadn't noticed the mention!

Comment: @ErickWong: For some reason, I miss fairly obvious applications of Rouché from time to time, so am sympathetic with requests involving its use :-).

Comment: I mistakenly thought that pointwise convergence on a compact set $\implies$ uniform convergence on that set, so I'm not completely sure now why $p_n \to p$ uniformly.

Comment: @user66825: A power series has the property of converging uniformly on compact subsets contained inside the radius of convergence (excuse my loose wording).

Comment: Does this argument for uniform convergence on $B(0, s)$ look right? On $B(0, s)$ we have $|(k+1)z^k| \le (k+1)s^k$, and $\sum (k+1)s^k$ converges since (applying the ratio test), $\lim \dfrac{(k+2)s^{k+1}}{(k+1)s^k} = s < 1$.  Therefore, the $\sum (k+1)z^k$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass $M$ test.

Comment: @user66825: Yes, that works. (However, the uniform convergence on compact subsets works for **any** power series inside its radius of convergence.)

Comment: In the last sentence, is something else being used besides the fact that $p$ is analytic in $B(0,1)$ and has no zeros?

Comment: @Tiberio: I'm not sure why I mentioned poles, the only relevant fact is that $p$ has no zeros on or in $|z|=r$ from which we get that $p_n$ has no zeros on or in $|z|=r$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

When $n\to \infty$, note that $p(z)=\displaystyle(\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}z^i)'\to(\cfrac{1}{1-z})'=\cfrac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ for $|z|<1$, which cannot be $0$.